# How to test the real-world performance of a social application without owning thousands of computers?

Tags: unit-testing, networking, testing, scalability, game-engine

I'm managing a prototypal design for an open-world social game which is supposed to replace a server which is having scaling issues. How can I test it's behavior in real-world situations - that is, hundreds of clients connected from different places - without having hundreds of clients to connect to it?

Answer (score 1):

There are several answers for that.

1. Professional load testing applications can do that. See [HP Load Runner](http://www8.hp.com/us/en/software-solutions/software.html?compURI=1175451&jumpid=reg_r1002_usen_c-001_title_r0001#.US-ZWDCnrp8) for instance
2. Open Source load testing applications - See [JMeter](http://jmeter.apache.org/)
3. Tweak other applications to do that. In my own case I am using [Selenium Grid](http://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/Grid2) where from using just 10 computers I can simulate 100 different users.

General answer is: If you do not have hundreds real users to do the real clicking, you will have to script user behaviour somehow and run these scripts in parallel from few computers.

Comment: I'll read on those, thanks! I have 4 computers at disposal, but only 1 connection, which won't make it fair to test TCP connectivity! I guess that will be a problem...

Comment: Well, that will be issue... For instance in my load testing I am using my work computer. Thanks to Selenium Grid i can simulate up to 10 users on one computer.

Answer (score 1):

In addition (or combined with) to the methods mentioned by @PavelJanicek, you can also manually limit the resources available to your application (memory, CPU time slots and priority) - this will allow the application to reach its limits with much less users.

Comment: Just little comment regarding this: Through my testing experience, I realised that assuming "environment with half the RAM and CPU will be half slowlier" is not *always* right...

Comment: @PavelJanicek agree, it's just another tool to assist